# Si8234 PWM with "disable" pin

Tags: pwm, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

in the datasheet of the [Si823x](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si823x.pdf) family of gate drivers, the Si8234 is mentioned as being a high-side/low-side driver with PWM input, but actually this "PWM" input pin is only there for switching between the High and the Low sides.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fctsoO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

in the absence of the "true" PWM functionality in the place where I was hoping to find it; can i use another pin, wich is the disable pin, as a "true" PWM input?:

according to the datasheet the Disable pin when it's active drives outputs VOA and VOB low; and -in consequence- both sides are disabled...

my question is:

is this behavior of this input pin and its fast switching time (60ns) sufficient to make it a PWM input?

Note: example of use: an H-Bridge DC Motor Driver.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0DKom.png)</sup>

Comment: _"but actually this "PWM" input pin is only there for switching between the High and the Low sides"_ - That's normally you want in a 'half-bridge' driver. From your timing diagrams it looks like you want to control a PMOS high side FET _or_ an NMOS lowside FET, is that correct? What is the application?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott: to clarify i added a schematic illustrating a case -among others- of what i want to have.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using PWM for direction and Disable for speed.
During the Disable time Q3 and Q4 are on placing a short across the motor. This will cause the motor to brake at 0% duty cycle.

Using the PWM pin will only, will cause 0%=fast forward, 50%=no current, 100%=fast reverse.

You cannot leave a top side MOSFET on for a long period of time. The top side needs to be turned off for a short time to recharge the capacitors across the powersupply.

I am not commenting on what you should do.  I use this IC in power supplies not with motors.